# How to tell if the computer is part of a domain or not

Tags: delphi, networking

Delphi Xe, Win7

I need the following function:

```
Function isPcInDomain:bool;
```

The domain name does not interest me, msdn LsaQueryInformationPolicy too (Or give realisation on Delphi). I would like to have a function that does no need to query the network.
Also it must still work if the local name of the computer contains a `.`

Tried to define a domain name, but on the personal computer which not in the domain - as a domain name gives out a name of Local Working group :(

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you restate it?

Comment: It is necessary to define simply, the personal computer in the domain or not (the network domain on Windows Server 2008). I do not know how still to explain.

Comment: For example, we have a network domain "MyCompany. Local". There is a computer with a name "Test". We enter into the domain. The computer name varies on "Test. MyCompany. Local". There is a computer with a name "Test2.pc" and local group "Home". What to write in a function body "isPcInDomain" that in 1 case has returned "True", and in the last - "False"?

Comment: @Gu - are you asking how you can tell if the current computer is in a domain, or if it is a standalone PC that is not part of a domain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [NetGetJoinInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

const
  netapi = 'netapi32.dll';

type
  TNetSetupJoinStatus = (NetSetupUnknownStatus, NetSetupUnjoined, NetSetupWorkgroupName, NetSetupDomainName);

function NetApiBufferFree(Buffer: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external netapi;
function NetGetJoinInformation(lpServer: PWideChar; out lpNameBuffer: PWideChar;
  out BufferType: TNetSetupJoinStatus): Cardinal; stdcall; external netapi;

procedure NetApiCheck(RetValue: Cardinal);
begin
  if RetValue <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    RaiseLastOSError(RetValue);
end;

function GetJoinInfo(out JoinStatus: TNetSetupJoinStatus): WideString;
var
  P: PWideChar;
begin
  NetApiCheck(NetGetJoinInformation(nil, P, JoinStatus));
  Result := P;
  NetApiBufferFree(P);
end;

procedure Main;
const
  JoinStatusStrings: array[TNetSetupJoinStatus] of string = ('Unknown', 'Unjoined', 'Workgroup', 'Domain');
var
  Info: TNetSetupJoinStatus;
  S: WideString;
begin
  S := GetJoinInfo(Info);
  Writeln(Format('%s %s', [JoinStatusStrings[Info], S]));
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ExitCode := 1;
      Writeln(Format('[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
uses
  LSAApi;

function isPcInDomain : Boolean;
var
  ComputerName : TLSAUnicodeStr;
  Attributes : TLsaObjectAttributes;
  PolicyHandle : LSA_HANDLE;
  Status : NTStatus;
  Buffer : Pointer;
  PolicyAccountDomainInfo : PPolicyAccountDomainInfo;
begin
  ComputerName := TLsaUnicodeStr.CreateFromStr('');
  try
    FillChar(Attributes, SizeOf(Attributes), 0);

    Status := LsaOpenPolicy(ComputerName.Value, Attributes, POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, PolicyHandle);
    if Status <> STATUS_SUCCESS then
      raise Exception.Create('LsaOpenPolicy Failed: '+SysErrorMessage(LsaNtStatusToWinError(Status)));

    try
      Status := LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle, PolicyPrimaryDomainInformation, Buffer);
      if Status <> STATUS_SUCCESS then
        raise Exception.Create('LsaQueryInformationPolicy Failed: '+SysErrorMessage(LsaNtStatusToWinError(Status)));

      try
        PolicyAccountDomainInfo := Buffer;
        Result := PolicyAccountDomainInfo.DomainSID <> nil
      finally
        LsaFreeMemory(Buffer)
      end;
    finally
      LsaClose(PolicyHandle)
    end;
  finally
    ComputerName.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, can write the reference on LsaApi.pas (or where to download)?

Comment: Ok, found: http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid06860D8F8B7701BD0B42D42112F4A47B08DCA76D.aspx?s=proxy